# Should we use only narrative methods in controllers when using Repository Pattern in Laravel 5.x?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, laravel-5, repository-pattern

I have a typical repository pattern structure in Laravel. Taking Fruits model as an example I have:

Class `EloquentFruitRepository` that extends abstract `EloquentRepository` that implements `FruitRepositoryInterface`.

`FruitRepositoryInterface` extends `RepositoryInterface`.

Finally `RepositoryInterface` defines those generic / shared methods like `all`, `find`, `with`, `create` etc.

I have read literally everything about Repository Pattern in Laravel 5. I reviewed all GitHub projects and reviewed all gists about that and... I have concern.

I like the approach of using just narrative methods, that in case of my Fruit model should sit in `EloquentFruitRepository`.

So in my controller instead of building the stuff like:

```
$fruits = $this->fruitRepository
    ->where('color', '=', 'yellow')
    ->where('is_available', '=', true)
    ->with(['comments'])
    ->orderBy([
        'sweetness' => 'asc'
    ])
    ->all();
```

is it better just to do

```
$fruits = $this->fruitRepository
    ->getAvailableYellowFruitsWithPeopleCommentsOrderedBySweetness();
```

and then define that method in `EloquentFruitRepository` like:

```
public function getAvailableYellowFruitsWithPeopleCommentsOrderedBySweetness(): Collection
{
    $model = $this->makeModel();

    $model
        ->where('color', '=', 'yellow')
        ->where('is_available', '=', true)
        ->with(['comments'])
        ->orderBy([
            'sweetness' => 'asc'
        ]);

    return $model->get() ?? new Collection();
}
```

So in general, should all those generic methods be used only within particular eloquent repositories or is it fine to use them also in controller?

Currently both ways work. I'm asking about best **(the very best) practice**, not anyone's preference.

**Should we only use narrative methods in controllers?**

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching for a 'very best' practice but, as you might know, when it comes to Design Patterns there isn't a general 'best practice' that fits all the situations

That being said, a general rule is: when you need a query in more than one point of your application, put it in a Repository. If you need it only once it's up to you

I'd put it in a repository too, but i'd name the method with a shorter and more readable name, i.e: `getAvailableYellowFruits`. To me the 'with' and 'order by' part is negligible and if you want you can always put that info in the comments of the method

Comment: As an aside, if you break out your repositories to represent different parts of your application logic and not just model access wrappers (the hard definition of a repository) then you can have a method such as mentioned above specific to that part of the app. For example an admin dashboard would use the Account model, which would have an AccountRepository. But there's no reason to not have an AdminRepository that returns accounts in a specific format for that part of the application (account list w/ ordering). There may be a better term for this though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Noted.